# Multer - Error: Unexpected field

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multipartform-data, multer

I'm getting a lengthy error when I try to pass my multipart form data to the back end:

```
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
    at emitMany (events.js:108:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Busboy.emit (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:208:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/Users/****/Documents/Programming Projects/JavaScript/Angular/Back-Yard-Brewing/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

I think I know what the issue is, I just don't know how to solve it. In my code, I use a service to append my multipart form, and then send it to the server. After that, I don't know what the image is named when it arrives at the server. So instead of just naming it "picture", I need to name it something more specific. Problem is, I don't know what. Here's my code:

**Front End**

```
            <label>Beer Name</label></br>
            <input ng-model="recipe.alias"></br>
            <label>Image</label></br>
            <input type="file" file-model="recipe.image">
            <label>Category</label></br>
            <select ng-options="beer.alias as beer.alias for beer in beerTypes" ng-model="recipe.selectedCategory" ng-change="filterByCategory(selectedCategory)">
            </select></br>
            <label>Description</label></br>
            <textarea maxlength="500" ng-model="recipe.description" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
            <p>Character count: {{recipe.description.length}} out of 500</p>
            <label>Instructions</label></br>
            <textarea maxlength="1000" ng-model="recipe.instructions" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
            <p> Character count: {{recipe.instructions.length}} out of 1000 (Minimum: 500)</p> 
            <button ng-click="createRecipe()" class="button-color btn btn-default">submit</button></br>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.recipe = {alias: null, selectedCategory: null, description: null, instructions: null, username: null, userID: null, image: null};

$scope.createRecipe = function(){
    authService.getUserInfo(function(user){
        // add the user information to the recipe
        $scope.recipe.username = user.username;
        $scope.recipe.userID = user._id;

    });
    multipartForm.post("/createrecipe", $scope.recipe);
}
```

**Angular Service**

```
.service("multipartForm", ["$http", function($http){
    this.post = function(uploadUrl, data){
        var fd = new FormData();
        for(key in data){
            fd.append(key, data[key]);
        }
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {"Content-Type" : undefined}
        });
    }
}]);
```

**Server File**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({ dest: "./uploads"})
var server = express();


var recipeController = require("./controllers/RecipeController")
var favRecipeController = require("./controllers/FavRecipeController")
var authenticationController = require('./controllers/Authentication');

var passportConfig = require('./config/passport');
var passport = require('passport');

//application configuration
//resave will keep it true

server.sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret            : "123iojojojoiklij",
    resave            : true,
    saveUninitialized : false,
    rolling           : true,
    cookie            : {maxAge: 60000 * 60}
});
server.use(server.sessionMiddleware);

//End Express Session Setup

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


server.use(passport.initialize());

server.use(passport.session());


server.post("/createrecipe", upload.single("picture"), recipeController.createRecipe);
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: multer has methods to specify file names and destination, did you check it?

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I'm not quite sure I understand. I know that once it reaches that back end, you refer to the file as req.file, but the problem I'm having is once it goes through the format.append in my service, I don't know what the image is named. Is there documentation that goes into what you said?

Comment: using multer you can access file's name being sent to it and even give a new one. use ng-file-upload for the front end, it'll make your task easy.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to post codes for the backend as well.

Comment: The name is the `name` attribute you put on the html element or you could log `fd` and see what it contains.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I added my front end to my question. What I'm confused about is all the multer examples I've seen weren't using objects, so when they passed it to the server, it was just a variable. I am using the `recipe` object, so I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: @ShanShan Where should I be looking in `fd`? Cause theres a lot of jargon that comes back.

Comment: Try with `fd.entries()`.

Comment: @ShanShan So my `fd.entriess` came back as `undefined`, but as it would turn out, I solved the issue; I was just using the wrong name for my image in my server post.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so a shout out to Gandalf the White and ShanShan for the answer:

As it turns out in my server.js, in my post to the server, my `single.upload("photo")` just needed to be `single.upload("image"),`, since that's what I had labeled it in my front end. Thank you for all your help.

Lesson learned: even if you are passing a multipart form via object, multer still sees it as what you originally labeled it as.